# Check if wordpress query was successfull or not

Tags: php, wordpress

I am executing a query which is as follows.

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'prousers';

$results = $wpdb->get_results("INSERT into $table_name 
                          (name,gender,mailid,empid,address,phone)
                           VALUES(
                           '".$InputName."','".$gender."','".$InputEmail."',
                           '".$emp_id."','".$address."','".$phn_num."'
                           )", OBJECT );
```

Everything is going well. I just wanted to validate it, so I did following:

```
if($results) { 
    echo'success';
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Values are correctly getting inserted into the table, but it is showing a fail message (it prints "error").

Why is this?

Comment: U didn't respond on answers

Comment: @devpro : was trying now my frnd... give me 10mins

Comment: @devpro : was trying now my frnd... give me 10mins

Comment: @devpro : i used your answer I am gettign this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prouser\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1986`

Comment: actually the format of insert was wrong ... it should be in arrays

Comment: Ohh great.. And sorry if I didn't help best of luck bro

Comment: @devpro : obviously you helped man.. thats why I upvoted. But I cannot accept two answers bro

Comment: Hahaha... True.. I know bro phpsmashcode deserve for this not mine ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row)

Then you will get details in $wpdb->insert_id to write condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `$wpdb->insert();` instead of `$wpdb->get_result();` as:

```
$wpdb->insert( "INSERT into $table_name (name,gender,mailid,empid,address,phone) VALUES('".$InputName."','".$gender."','".$InputEmail."', '".$emp_id."','".$address."','".$phn_num."')", OBJECT );
```

And right after this use this for getting last Id:

```
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

And check either query execute or not as:

```
if($lastid > 0) { 
    echo'success'; 
} 
else { 
    echo "error"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use die function with get_results() method,

```
 global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'prousers';

                $results = $wpdb->get_results( "INSERT into $table_name 
                          (name,gender,mailid,empid,address,phone)
                          VALUES('".$InputName."','".$gender."','".$InputEmail."',

                        '".$emp_id."','".$address."','".$phn_num."')", OBJECT ) or die('Error while query run');
```